# How to get html of matched element in jquery

Tags: jquery, innerhtml

I have this html

```
<div id"test123">
dasd'asdasd

</div>
```

I want the content of that div box with `"<div id="test123">"` itself as well not just innerhtml

I tried `$('#test123').html()`

But it only gave me inner html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't seem to be an easy way in the box.

http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2007/06/17/jquery-snippets-outerhtml/

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative, which looks more linear/nicer to me:
`var html = $('#foo').wrap('<div/>').parent().html();
$('#foo').unwrap();`

found here:
http://codeasp.net/blogs/raghav_khunger/microsoft-net/751/jquery-how-to-get-html-of-a-div-with-that-div-tag-included

Answer (score 0):

```
var div = $('#test123').eq(0);
console.log(div);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty gnarly, but it gets the job done:

```
$('<div />').append($('#test123').clone()).html();
```